# SQL Query - select name with max projects and least projects

Tags: sql

I need to create a query that displays the Manager and Department name for the Department with the most number projects and least number of projects based on this database scheme. I can't figure out how to determine the most amount and least amount of projects.
[Database Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5vPR.png)

Comment: Where's your attempt?  This looks like a homework question.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by joining together any needed data. You're going to need Manager name, so we'll need to join the `employee` table.

```
SELECT 
    e.fname, d.dname
FROM 
    department d
LEFT JOIN 
    employee e ON e.ssn = d.mgr_ssn
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         department.dnumber, COUNT(*) [projects]
     FROM 
         department
     LEFT JOIN 
         project on department.dnumber = project.dnum
     GROUP BY 
         department) total ON d.dnumber = total.dnumber
HAVING 
    total.projects = MAX(total.projects)
```